# bx slider slider last slide always some part hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

Hi i m using bxslider plugin and used to min and max slide

but my problum is my slider allways shwo to last slide some part is hidden how to resolve it. i have try to some time but not find any solution my code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>TIL </title>
 
  <!-- Google will often use this as its description of your page/site. Make it good. -->

     <meta name="google-site-verification" content="">
     <!-- Speaking of Google, don't forget to set your site up: http://google.com/webmasters -->

     <meta name="author" content="">
     <meta name="Copyright" content="Copyright  2015. All Rights Reserved.">

     <meta name="DC.title" content="Project Name">
     <meta name="DC.subject" content="What you're about.">
     <meta name="DC.creator" content="Who made this site.">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">  
     

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
      <link href="http://www.buylic.in/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

      <!-- Custom CSS -->
      <link href="http://www.buylic.in/css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet" />

      <!-- Custom Fonts -->
      <link href="http://www.buylic.in/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

      <!-- Contact form -->
     <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

      <!-- Custom CSS -->
      <link href="http://www.buylic.in/css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
      <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
 
 
</head>
<body id="home">
 <!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="">Profolio</div>
  <!-- Header End here -->
  <!-- Body Start here -->
  <!-- Header Carousel -->
   

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        
        <!-- Marketing Icons Section -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <div class="row">
                   asdf asd fasd fasd fasd fasd
                    
                    
                    
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              ============= ------------
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- /.row -->

        <hr>

        <!-- Testimonial Section -->
        <h2>Testimonials</h2>
<div class="well">
 <ul class="bxslider">
   <li>
    <div class="testimonil">
     <h5>Rakesh Kumar</h5>
     <blockquote class="quotes">
    <p>
     Mes cuml dia sed in lacus ut eniascet etor ingerto aliiqt es sitet amet eismod ictorut dolore ligulate ameti dapi licdu nt mtsent lusto dolor ltisim comme. Mes cuml dia sed inertio lacus ut eniascet ingerto aliiqt sit eism odictor. 
    </p>
   </blockquote>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="testimonil">
     <h5>Vijay Kumar2</h5>
     <blockquote class="quotes">
    <p>
     Mes cuml dia sed in lacus ut eniascet etor ingerto aliiqt es sitet amet eismod ictorut dolore ligulate ameti dapi licdu nt mtsent lusto dolor ltisim comme. Mes cuml dia sed inertio lacus ut eniascet ingerto aliiqt sit eism odictor. 
    </p>
   </blockquote>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="testimonil">
     <h5>Rohit Kumar3</h5>
     <blockquote class="quotes">
    <p>
     Mes cuml dia sed in lacus ut eniascet etor ingerto aliiqt es sitet amet eismod ictorut dolore ligulate ameti dapi licdu nt mtsent lusto dolor ltisim comme. Mes cuml dia sed inertio lacus ut eniascet ingerto aliiqt sit eism odictor. 
    </p>
   </blockquote>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="testimonil">
     <h5>Suresh Kumar11</h5>
     <blockquote class="quotes">
    <p>
     Mes cuml dia sed in lacus ut eniascet etor ingerto aliiqt es sitet amet eismod ictorut dolore ligulate ameti dapi licdu nt mtsent lusto dolor ltisim comme. Mes cuml dia sed inertio lacus ut eniascet ingerto aliiqt sit eism odictor. 
    </p>
   </blockquote>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="testimonil">
     <h5>Ravi Kumar22</h5>
     <blockquote class="quotes">
    <p>
     Mes cuml dia sed in lacus ut eniascet etor ingerto aliiqt es sitet amet eismod ictorut dolore ligulate ameti dapi licdu nt mtsent lusto dolor ltisim comme. Mes cuml dia sed inertio lacus ut eniascet ingerto aliiqt sit eism odictor. 
    </p>
   </blockquote>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="testimonil">
     <h5>Rakesh Kumar33</h5>
     <blockquote class="quotes">
    <p>
     Mes cuml dia sed in lacus ut eniascet etor ingerto aliiqt es sitet amet eismod ictorut dolore ligulate ameti dapi licdu nt mtsent lusto dolor ltisim comme. Mes cuml dia sed inertio lacus ut eniascet ingerto aliiqt sit eism odictor. 
    </p>
   </blockquote>
    </div>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
    <!-- =========================================================================== -->
    
    <!-- =========================================================================== -->
    <!-- Footer here  -->
     <!-- Footer here  -->
     <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <hr />
                        <ul class="footerLinking">
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        Rohit azad
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    <!-- Footer here end  -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="http://www.buylic.in/js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://www.buylic.in/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://www.buylic.in/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Contact form -->
    <script >
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        controls: false,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 3,
        slideWidth: 300,
        slideMargin: 10
    });

});    
    </script>
    <script ></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have define width 300px for testimonial one item width. But I expect container width is 1170px because you are using Bootstrap. So, container width and items width not equal to show all testimonial contents. That is why your problem occurring. Define item width according to the container width. Then you can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

just put this in your css

```
      .bx-wrapper {
       max-width: 930px!important;
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the two wrapping divs around ul.bxslider,that are generated by the BXslider plugin, have 5px border around them each set in the css, these borders are substracted from the overall calculated viewport of a slider - which is in your case 920px (3x300px + 2x10px margins), causing the last image not to be seen completely. If you unset these borders, your slider will fit just perfectly (on a large screen)

**[demo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/opghbqot/4/)**

alternatively, you can change the box-sizing of these divs to "content-box" in order there borders are not included into the total width.

```
.bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
   box-sizing: content-box;
}
.bx-viewport{   
  box-shadow:none !important;
}
```

**[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/opghbqot/6/)**